# Why can't I receive a notification email on Trello?

Tags: trello

After registration with some email I get:

> Confirm Email
>
> We sent an email to nuvem@nuvemk.com with a verification link. It
>   might take some time to show up, but when it does you will be ready to
>   use Trello.

The thing is, I don't see any email.

I've tried this address as well:

https://trello.com/resendValidate

I've placed my email several times, and I can't receive any email at all. Yes, the email is correct. Yes, Trello has sent me other emails to this email, for example when I was invited. But I haven't received any email for **registering**.

Is this a manual process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please contact support@trello.com. We can provide you with logs to take to your mail administrator that will help them track down the missing messages.

Answer (score 2):

Try visiting

https://trello.com/test_notifications

This page will allow you to send a test notification to yourself to verify that the notifications process is working for your account.  If it isn't working, you should contact support@trello.com

Comment: I cannot send a test_notification because I'm not logged in. This user, the user I'm trying to register, can't access that page.